# SQL select based on pipe split

Tags: sql

I have a column called `Data1` the column contains the following data `"Apples|Farmer|11"`

How do I select `"Farmer"` from `Data1` in a select

```
select data1 from tblMyTable
```

Comment: Is the data actually being _stored_ this way, or is this some sort of 'temporary' processing file?

Comment: Data is being stored this way... not by my choice

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT   SUBSTRING_INDEX('Apples|Farmer|11', '|', 2)`

Comment: How does this select the column?

Comment: And added the MySQL tag, this was NEVER a mysql question

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(data1, '|', 2)

Comment: Not a MySQL question whoever edited the question made it a MySQL question

Comment: @Mike: [It looks](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8581815/1) like *Mysql* was in the title from the beginning. Someone merely added the `mysql` and other tags based on that. Anyway, if this is not a MySQL question, then you should probably specify which one it is. In my opinion, tagging it as `sql` is not enough, as different SQL flavours may have different means for solving this particular type of problem.

Comment: @Jauzsika - This gets the position of the first instance of the pipe character (`|`), or possibly the second - how does this translate into selecting the second 'column' worth of data?